# Inner Join with count on 3 tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-server

We have 3 tables

1. membersurlss with fields ID, Username, ...
2. users with fields ID, Username,.....
3. matrix1 with fields ID, Username ....

Now we want to have 2 checks in the query.

1. All 3 tables Username field value must match.
2. only that record is picked up randomly which more than 1 entry in membersurls table.

This is the query we tried but it didn't found the properly, means it is always picking up 1 record but not picking up any other random record.

```
select membersurlss.Username, COUNT(membersurlss.ID) 
from membersurlss 
INNER JOIN users ON membersurlss.Username=users.Username 
INNER JOIN matrix1 ON matrix1.Username=users.Username 
having COUNT(membersurlss.ID)>1 
order by rand() limit 0,1
```

We want to pick up a random record.

Comment: COUNT without GROUP BY will return only one row. Try `GROUP BY membersurlss.Username`. However - it still can return wrong result, if a Username occures multiple times in other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will count the IDs for all users. In order to count the IDs for each user, you need to use `GROUP BY membersurlss.Username`.

```sql
select membersurlss.Username, COUNT(membersurlss.ID) 
from membersurlss 
INNER JOIN users ON membersurlss.Username=users.Username 
INNER JOIN matrix1 ON matrix1.Username=users.Username
GROUP BY membersurlss.Username
having COUNT(membersurlss.ID)>1 
order by rand() limit 0,1
```

This should work, if `Username` in `users` and `matrix1` tables are unique.

If `membersurlss.ID` is unique (or the primary key) you should use `DISTINCT` in order to count only occurances in the `membersurlss` table:

```sql
select membersurlss.Username, COUNT(DISTINCT membersurlss.ID) 
from membersurlss 
INNER JOIN users ON membersurlss.Username=users.Username 
INNER JOIN matrix1 ON matrix1.Username=users.Username
GROUP BY membersurlss.Username
having COUNT(DISTINCT membersurlss.ID)>1 
order by rand() limit 0,1
```